# How can I modify /System/Library/ScriptingDefinitions/CocoaStandard.sdef and have the changes persist?

Tags: macos, applescript, recovery, automation, library

I'm trying to modify `/System/Library/ScriptingDefinitions/CocoaStandard.sdef`. I want to do this because a lot of applications reference this file in their own scripting definitions, and I want to experiment with adding new stuff that will take effect in every application. Since scripting definition entries map directly to Cocoa objects and their methods, I figure this would be an effective way to mess with other applications' objects.

I rebooted to Recovery OS and ran the following commands in a terminal:

```
csrutil disable
umount "/Volumes/Macintosh HD"
mkdir /Volumes/mhd
mount /dev/disk3s1 /Volumes/mhd
cd /Volumes/mhd/System/Library/ScriptingDefinitions
mv CocoaStandard.sdef CocoaStandard.sdef.original
ln -s /Library/ScriptingDefinitions/CocoaStandard.sdef .
reboot
```

Note that I have already placed a copy of `CocoaStandard.sdef` in `/Library/ScriptingDefinitions`.

The problem I'm running into is that, despite disabling System Integrity Protection, once I reboot into macOS, the changes I made in `/System/Library/ScriptingDefinitions` have somehow been reverted. There is no `CocoaStandard.sdef.original`, and `CocoaStandard.sdef` is once again a regular file rather than a symbolic link.

How do I stop these changes from being reverted? Alternatively, if there is a better way to add custom scripting definitions to existing applications, that would work as well. (I tried directly adding entries to the .sdef inside a copy of the application, but then whenever I try to control that copy of the application using AppleScript, I get error -1728.)

Comment: What OS are you running?  Note that macOS 11 (Big Sur) and later use cryptographic protection with a signed system volume - the read-only System volume is now sealed and will not accept any changes without a valid signature from Apple.

Comment: I think you should add changes to /Library/Scripting Additions, instead.

Comment: @benwiggy: Will that let me control other applications' internal objects, like if I added stuff to an application's built-in .sdef file?

Comment: I don't know, but the usual paradigm is to augment the system in /Library, not to modify the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read later that (like @red_menace pointed out in the comments) the behavior was caused by the sealed system volume. I haven't done this, but `csrutil authenticated-root disable` at the recovery terminal should prevent it from occurring. But according to [this page](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/words-of-caution-regarding-modification-of-system-files-using-csrutil-authenticated-root-disable.2276764/), there are various reasons why that might not be desirable, especially for something that can be accomplished in other ways.

Specifically, the way I found that works was to create a disk image in Disk Utility, and then mount it at `/System/Library/ScriptingDefinitions`. This will temporarily replace the contents of the directory with the contents of the disk image without actually modifying anything on disk. The basic steps to do that are:

1. Open Disk Utility.
2. File->New Image->Blank Image...
3. Set a smaller file size (I used 16 MB, though even that is an awful lot) and save the disk image. I saved it to the desktop as ScriptDefs.dmg.
4. Place the modified CocoaStandard.sdef in the mounted disk image, and eject it.
5. Open Terminal.
6. `hdiutil attach ~/Desktop/ScriptDefs.dmg`
7. Look at the list that appears, and find the `/dev/disk#s#` listed at the bottom.
8. `sudo mount -t apfs -o nobrowse /dev/disk#s# /System/Library/ScriptingDefinitions` (replacing `disk#s#` with the values from above)

According to my testing, this will (understandably) fail with a "permission denied" error if System Integrity Protection is enabled, so you'll have to disable that first. Also, don't create a compressed DMG, because for whatever reason that'll fail with the same error even if SIP is off.

Comment: What was the outcome of modifying `CocoaStandard.sdef` ?  Did it affect anything ?

Comment: @CJK: Yes; it had the effect I was expecting, for the most part. I managed to make the toolbar in Messages customizable, though moving the buttons around resulted in a broken appearance and the changes didn't save. I just did that as a test, however.